# Insert into duplicate key and replace into does not work

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `pv_network_coverage` (
  `network_group_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `carrier_group_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `physician_count` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `facility_count` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pcp_count` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `update_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`network_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;

REPLACE INTO pv_network_coverage(carrier_group_id,
                                 network_group_id,
                                 physician_count,
                                 facility_count,
                                 pcp_count,
                                 update_time) SELECT *FROM temp_pv_network_coverage;
```

I use `replace into` and `insert into` with duplicate keys.

[image]
The physician_count should be 1000 but still 0..

It really makes me surprised.

Comment: what do you mean "the rows will be affected" and "original data is not changed"?  those seem to be saying the opposite.  how about showing some actual before and after data?

Comment: 2 rows affected after I execute the replace into sql,  but data is not updated

Comment: do `SELECT * FROM temp_pv_network_coverage` produce the same field names as pv_network_coverage? Try naming the fields in the select statement.

Comment: @brendan62269 yes

Comment: are the data types for each field also the same?

Comment: I fixed the issue,  Not to use select columns From instead of select * from

Answer (score 0):

Remember to select columns instead of select *from